# C++ / warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner today and trying to learn desktop programming with C++. And I am confused that why doesnt this work:

The code:

```
int math(int opt, int x, int y){
    switch(opt){
        case 1:
            return x + y;
            break;
        case 2:
            return x - y;
            break;
        case 3:
            return x * y;
            break;
        case 4:
            return x / y;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The use:
`cout << to_string(math(1,1,2)));`

The error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int math(int, int, int)’:
main.cpp:38:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   38 | }
      | ^
```

Thank you all,
as I understand:

- break; after return is extra because will be never executed
- need to return something in all cases(i.e. if opt is bigger than 5)

So this works now:

```
int math(int opt, int x, int y){
    switch(opt){
        case 1:
            return x + y;
        case 2:
            return x - y;
        case 3:
            return x * y;
        case 4:
            return x / y;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the function return in the `default` case?

Comment: Firstly that is only a warning, so saying that it doesn't work is not true. But to understand the warning consider what value your `math` function will return if `opt` equals `5` (say). See the problem?

Comment: BTW, putting `break;` immediately after `return ...;` is a waste of time. When you return you leave the function so the break is never executed.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: Use [an `enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) for `opt` instead of an `int`. The compiler can spot potential mistakes more easily and something like `cout << to_string(math(option::add,1,2)));` is significantly more descriptive than having just another anonymous number in there.

Comment: In that "never happen" case at the end of the function, I'd put a `throw std::logic_error("the impossible has happened");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, if you pass "invalid" `opt` value, `default` case gets selected, and your function returns nothing. So one solution would be to decide what to return if you pass invalid `opt`.

You should fix your problem like this:

```
enum class Opt { PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDED };

int math(Opt opt, int x, int y) {
    switch(opt){
        case Opt::PLUS:
            return x + y;
        case Opt::MINUS:
            return x - y;
        case Opt::TIMES:
            return x * y;
        case Opt::DIVIDED:
            return x / y;
    }
    // it is important to not have default: case
    // above because now compiler will issue warning,
    // you add new values to Opt.

    // below line should never be reached, so value doesn't matter,
    // but it's needed to disable warning on some compilers.
    return 0;
}

// test
int main() { 
    return math(Opt::PLUS, 1, 2); // exit code 3
}
```

Using `enum class` has the benefit, that if you want to shoot yourself into foot by passing random integer as `opt`, you have use an explicit cast to convert the integer into an enum class value.

Comment: Your comment is [inacurate](https://godbolt.org/z/e68rafqhE).  The compiler will still warn, because there's still a path through the function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: From my experience, Clang and GCC don't issue warnings in this case because they assume all possible paths are covered. But MSVC issues a warning, which is frustrating. I finally found a solution for this type of recurring situation.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I guess that depends. I tested with this: https://godbolt.org/z/818Tx9KE7 : `gcc -O3 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -std=c18` gives no warnings (but does warn if for example one `case` is commented out).

Comment: @hyde Well, [compiling it as C++](https://godbolt.org/z/8Gz46vfjb) issues a warning.

Comment: @NathanPierson Oops, should check the tags.... I'll edit proper C++ solution.

Comment: @NathanPierson It's compiling with GCC rather than Clang (as C or C++) that made it issue a warning.  Clang really _should_ issue a warning here IMO, like both MSVC and GCC do.

Comment: My trick is: having a global function `[[noreturn]] inline void unreachableCode() { abort(); }`, that I call after the `switch` when I expect impossible path. The name is self-descriptive. Because of the `[[noreturn]]`, the compiler won't issue a warning. And in case there is a violation of the assumption, it is not undefined behavior, since the program just aborts (possibly as a break if run in a debugger).

Comment: I guess adding a `return 0;` for the impossible path will trigger another warning on Clang about unreachable code. This is why I came up with the previously described trick.

Comment: @prapin Also adding a return will screw up some optimizations... On *gcc* at least. Which is kind of funny, but not in a fun way. https://godbolt.org/z/q9Ys7hc8T

Comment: @prepin With quick testing with _godbolt_, I did not get warning about unreachable code with *clang* with the options I used. Interestingly enough _clang_ does not warn about missing `return` either, if that is commented out.

Comment: A fan of a `throw` or log and abort instead of `return 0;` as a last line of defense, but with the `enum class` the only way to get in there with an invalid value is if you add a new value to the `enum` and forget to update the function (probably get a compiler warning) or you play Russian Roulette with a cast.

Comment: Interesting though that GCC misses out on some potential optimizations if you add a throw.

Comment: The "Russian Roulette" cast is valid C++. It is legal (and normal) for C++ enums to have values other than the enumerators. That's why it's not actually unreachable, and why compilers may choose to warn.

Comment: @JeffGarrett With a old school `enum` I'll agree with you, with a couple anti-stupidity caveats we'll all probably agree on, but when you use a scoped `enum` the typing rules get much stricter, and one of the main reasons you use a scoped `enum` is to get those stricter rules working for you. Turning them back off with a cast is something you should think about very hard before doing, and when you do, you guard that region of code very, very carefully.

Comment: I didn't say it was good, or that you should, just that it is valid and used. Also, to be clear, the "cast" doesn't actually have to be a cast... Direct initialization works too. `Opt o{42}`

Answer (score 3):

A function that has any return type other than `void` needs to reach a `return` statement with the correct value type specified.

A function is built like this: `returnType name(type parameterName, ...){}`

If the return type is (as in your case) an `int`, the path of execution must reach a `return foo;` statement, where `foo` is, or convertible to, an `int`.

```
int math(int opt, int x, int y){
    switch(opt){
        case 1:
            return x + y;
        case 2:
            return x - y;
        case 3:
            return x * y;
        case 4:
            return x / y;
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("math parameter opt out of range!");
    }
}
```

Also, any code after reaching a `return` is not executed, so the `break;` statements are extraneous.

Comment: I wanted to avoid adding new information for a new programmer, but you are right it is a better way of handling this.